# The subspace associated with the affine set $C$ is the nullspace of $A$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

This is an example from my book:

Example 2.1: The solution set of a system of linear
equations, $C = \{ x | Ax = b\}$,  Where  $A \in R^{m\times n}$ and $b \in R^m$, is an affine set. To show this suppose $x_1, x_2 \in C$ then for any $\theta$ we have:

$
A(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2) = \theta Ax_1 + (1-\theta)Ax_2 = \theta b + (1-\theta)b = b
$
Which shows that the affine combination $\theta x_1 +(1-\theta)x_2 $ is also in C.  The subspace associated with the affine set $C$ is the nullspace of $A$.

I understand the proof but I cant understand the last sentence. From what I know if $x$ is a solution for $Ax = b$ Then every linear combination of x is a also a solution, And that is the definition of the range space. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nullspace of a matrix $A$ is the set of vectors $v$ for which $Av=0$. Basically, what it’s saying is that the general solution to the system is the sum of a particular solution $x_0$ and the solution to the homogeneous system $Ax=0$.

Comment: so can we say that the confusing sentence makes perfect sense if we have $b=0$?

Comment: @FrankMoses I think the key to understanding that sentence is that an affine set $C$ can be defined as $\{x\mid x-v\in W\}$, where $v$ is some fixed vector and $W$ is a subspace of the parent space. In your case, the null space of $A$ plays the role of $W$ and $v$ is any particular solution of the system. Visualized in the plane, $W$ could be a line through the origin and $C$ is then any line parallel to it.

Answer (score 0):

**The last sentence is** :
*The subspace associated with the affine set $C$ is the nullspace of $A$.*

**To prove**:
For any point, $x_i$ from subspace $V$, we have $Ax_i = 0$

**Proof**:
Let the associated subspace:
$V = C - x_0 = \{ x-x_0|x \in C\}$
for a particular point, $x_0\in C$.
Then for any point $x_i = x - x_0$ in $V$, we have $Ax_i = A(x - x_0) = Ax - Ax_0 = b - b = 0$.

**Hence proved** that $V$ is nullspace of $A$.